# How do I fill in the colour of this shape?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle

t.fillcolor("pink")
t.pencolor("red")

for x in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        t.begin_fill()
        right(36)
        t.forward(15)
        t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.right(36)
    t.forward(90)
    t.pendown()
```

This was my code to make the program draw 10 decagons in a circle, while filling the shapes in pink and leaving the lines in red. But no matter what, it says that the string has no attribute to the colour. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found three errors. First, you must instantiate `Turtle` by using parentheses:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

Second, you forgot the object on the `right(36)` call in the inner loop.

```
t.right(36)
```

Finally, move the `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` outside the inner loop so that it fills each decagon, not each line segment of each decagon.